# How to make li active after page loads

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am having a list which is reused in other webpage so i included it in one file and require the same in other webpage where required

I want to make them active for example if MY RESUME IS CLICKED THE li of myresume become active instead of dashboard so i implement jquery in the same file
but everytime i click on other link other than dashboard the active class is only present in Dashboard l . Is it due to because every time I am going to other page the active class is present on dashboard or due to jquery code(i have included cdn of jquery)??

```css
.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="active"><a href="dashboard.php"><i class="ti-dashboard"></i>Dashboard</a></li>
  <li><a href="resume.php"><i class="ti-wallet"></i>My Resume</a></li>
  <li><a href="employer-list.php"><i class="ti-wallet"></i>Browse Jobs</a></li>
  <li><a href="assess.php?q=1"><i class="ti-wallet"></i>Assessment</a></li>
  <li><a href="jobs.php"><i class="ti-hand-point-right"></i>Applied Jobs</a></li>
</ul>
```

What i want is that my li become active after my page loads not  after clicked

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("li").click(function() {
        // remove classes from all
        $("li").removeClass("active");
        // add class to the one we clicked
        $(this).addClass("active");
      });
    });
```

Comment: this is a backend work since your are reloading the page. a JS way is only useful if you have a one page site

Comment: can you provide refrence for the same

Comment: you can use pass value in url and after get this value using $_GET and compare this value and put active class in li tag

Comment: @mass Add active class on element in document ready function using jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, give your url name as the class name for all the *li* like below

```
<ul> 
<li class="dashboard"><a href="dashboard.php"><i class="ti-dashboard"></i>Dashboard</a></li>
  <li class="resume"><a href="resume.php"><i class="ti-wallet"></i>My Resume</a></li>
  <li class="employer-list"><a href="employer-list.php"><i class="ti-wallet"></i>Browse Jobs</a></li>
  <li class="assess"><a href="assess.php?q=1"><i class="ti-wallet"></i>Assessment</a></li>
  <li class="jobs"><a href="jobs.php"><i class="ti-hand-point-right"></i>Applied Jobs</a></li>
</ul>
```

Then change your jQuery as below, logic is that, from the url will get the class name you given for each li and assign active class accordingly.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  var relativePath = location.pathname.split("/");
  var activeMenu = relativePath[relativePath.length-1].replace(".php", "")[0];
    $('li.'+activeMenu).addClass("active");
});
```